# Can't set locale to en_US.UTF-8, but locale -a says it's available. No root

Tags: linux, utf-8, locale, rhel-6

I'm trying to use powerline symbols in gvim. Part of that requires that I set my locale to UTF-8.

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Afterwards I see the following errors.

For gvim:

```
bash-4.1$ /usr/bin/gvim

(process:14055): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

For perl

```
bash-4.1$ perl -de0
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC__FASTMSG = "true",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I've tried setting `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, and `LC_ALL`. I've tried both `en_US.UTF-8` and `en_US.utf8`. When I run `locale -a` this is a subset of what it says is available.

```
en_US
en_US.iso88591
en_US.iso885915
en_US.utf8
```

I'm running on a remote rhel 6 image where I don't have admin privileges. I suspect that I don't actually have UTF-8 available. Is there a way to generate this locale and keep it in my home directory without root? Is there an alternative way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read through locale manpages and checked all the paths and environment variables it uses. It turns out my system had `LOCPATH` set to a nonexistent path. I now unset that variable in my profile. The locale points to the right directory and everything works.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enclose `en_US.UTF-8` in quotation marks (") like it shows in your php error warning message. As it reads now, you're setting the variable `LC_ALL` equal to the variable `en_US.UTF-8`; you want to assign that variable to the string value 'en_US.UTF-8'.

Comment: I'm setting the LC_ALL variable in bash. `en_US.UTF-8` is not being interpreted as a variable since there is no `$` sigil present. Adding quotes does not have any impact.